# PHP Warning: Attempt to read property "id" on null

Tags: php, variables

I'm receiving a php warning in the error when I run the below script in the footer.php file.
The code works but is there is a way to write it better?

```php
<?php

 global $product;

    $mpn = array_shift( wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'pa_mpn', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) ) );
    
    $brand = array_shift( wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'pa_brand', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) ) );
    
    ?>  

    
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      var ccs_cc_args = ccs_cc_args || [];
      
      // Main Product Page
      ccs_cc_args.push(['cpn', 'CPN']);
      ccs_cc_args.push(['mf', '<?php echo $brand; ?> ']);
      ccs_cc_args.push(['pn', '<?php echo $mpn; ?>']);
      ccs_cc_args.push(['upcean', 'UPC_EAN_CODE']);
      ccs_cc_args.push(['ccid', 'CATALOG_CODE']);
      ccs_cc_args.push(['lang', 'LANGUAGE']);
      ccs_cc_args.push(['market', 'MARKET']);
      
      (function () {
         var o = ccs_cc_args; o.push(['_SKey', '']); o.push(['_ZoneId', '6ce9a32538']);
         var sc = document.createElement('script'); sc.type = 'text/javascript'; sc.async = true;
         sc.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'cdn.cs.1worldsync.com/jsc/h1ws.js';
         var n = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; n.parentNode.insertBefore(sc, n);
      })();
      </script>
```

Comment: On which line, the $mpn and $brand lines? Then I guess you're running this even when $product is null i.e. even when this isn't a product page.

Comment: You could also use [wp_add_inline_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/) to pass the mpn and brand into an enqueued script block rather than inlining your complete tracking code. That would also avoid any problems escaping your strings for inclusion in JavaScript strings, which you're not doing. And I guess you don't really want to pass dummy values into upcean etc.?

Comment: you've written `$product->id` and assumed that there will always be a `$product` in `global $product` but this is incorrect! E.g. if you were on a login page which product would `$product` be? You need to check assumptions using `if` conditions before doing things

Answer (score 2):

`$product->id` only works if `$product` has a value, and sometimes it does not! E.g. on a login page which product would it be?

So you need to check if it's valid/exists/safe with an `if` check:

```php
global $product;
if ( ! empty( $product ) ) {
    // code that uses $product goes here
}
```